# Error building Player: IOException: Failed to Move File

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error when I try to use my .aar plugin created in android studio on Unity 3d

```
Error building Player: IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\app-release\classes.jar' to 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\app-release\libs\classes.jar'.
```

Answer (score 14):

Use *provided* scope in gradle.

https://sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

```
dependencies 
{
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ, Thanks.

Comment: "provided" scope has now been replaced by "compileOnly".

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove 'libs/classes.jar' in your aar(use your favorate archive manager, it's just ZIP file), since Unity will inject it by self. Unity will fail if there's already one.

Comment: I need that in my android plugin because I import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
If I don't use it, I cannot use UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() in java side.

Answer (score 0):

Im working with the Unity-Editor and visual Studio. What did work for me was simply removing these files mentioned in the error log.The Editor managed to build after that on my android device. My game was running perfectly fine since then.